JSR-352 batch job delays between chunks: how to reduce commit time without bulk delete?
I am running a JSR-352 batch job (concretely, Apache JBatch as implementation) in a JEE environment (WebSphere with EclipseLink as the JPA provider).
The batch processes database records in chunks and deletes entities based on their IDs with some condition. The problem is that after a chunk of entities is deleted, the next chunk is read only after a delay of several minutes, with the delay increasing proportionally to the chunk size, so e.g.:

Chunk size = 50: Delay between chunks is ~10 minutes.
Chunk size = 10: Delay between chunks is ~2 minutes.

My job configuration:

A reader fetches IDs from the database based on a condition. I limit the query results using query.setMaxResults(chunkSize) to avoid fetching all IDs at once.
A writer deletes entities by their IDs in a loop using em.remove, ensuring cascading deletions are handled properly for each entity.

The job works but slows down significantly as chunk size increases. My setup includes:

A connection pool configured in WebSphere.
JPA managed transactions (JTA).

I tried also bulk deletes like  DELETE FROM Entity WHERE id IN (...) but this not an option for me because they do not cascade deletions to related entities. The entity I want to delete is very complex and in the logs I can see that deleting this entity result in deleting rows from about 50 tables (whether this is a good design is another question)
Using em.flush() in my writer after processing each chunk leads to transaction timeout, so therefore I don't use flush.
What I have also observed is that em.clear() after each chunk without flush solves the stuck problem, but the changes are not committed to the database. So just doing clear is also not correct. EntityManager might be holding too many managed entities, or database locks/constraints could be causing the slowdown but I've tried a lot, but I don't know how to solve this problem.
Here is the code for my Reader:
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.batch.api.chunk.AbstractItemReader;
import javax.batch.runtime.context.StepContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.apache.batchee.cdi.scope.StepScoped;

@StepScoped
@Named
public class MyReader implements AbstractItemReader {

    private int chunkSize = 50;
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    private List<Long> currentIdsInChunk;
    private int currentBatchPosition = 0;
    
    ...constructor

    ...reading the chunksize from batch properties

    @Override
    public Long readItem() throws Exception {
    
        if (currentIdsInChunk == null || currentBatchPosition >= currentIdsInChunk.size()) {
            LOGGER.info("Loading Ids for the next chunk...");
             currentIdsInChunk = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT e.id FROM Entity e WHERE e.condition = :condition")
                              .setParameter("condition", "SOME_CONDITION")
                              .setMaxResults(chunkSize)
                              .getResultList();
            if (currentIdsInChunk.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            currentBatchPosition = 0;
        }
        return currentIdsInChunk.get(currentBatchPosition++);
    }


    @Override
    public Serializable checkpointInfo() {
        return currentBatchPosition;
    }
}

My writer look like this:
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.apache.batchee.extras.typed.NoStateTypedItemWriter;

@Named
@Dependent
public class MyDeleteWriter implements NoStateTypedItemWriter<Long> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    ... constructor

    @Override
    public void writeItems(List<Long> ids) throws Exception {
        int deletedCount = 0;
        for (Long id : ids) {
            Entity entity = em.find(Entity.class, id);
            if (entityToDelete != null) {
                if (!em.contains(entityToDelete)) {
                    entityToDelete = em.merge(entityToDelete);
                }
                em.remove(entityToDelete);
                deletedCount++;
                
            } else {
                // log entity does not exist
            }
        }
        
    }
}


You have to profile your app to figure out why this is a mess. Pointers: flush then clear will allow freeing up memory. If flush is leading to 'timeouts' you are doing something wrong - chances are you are just processing too many objects in the graph and need to prune what is getting loaded - try using lazy loading and fetch graphs to more efficiently load only what is required for the delete process - generally only what it'll need to cascade the delete over.  PS what is that entityToDelete != null logic? you shouldn't need to merge something and then delete it and might be adding overhead

Flush cause JPA to go over all managed objects looking for changes, so repeated flushes can be a problem if you don't call clear, as it'll look for changes in the same objects repeatedly. Also check if/how weaving is enabled and that your entities are using change tracking as it is generally faster. And if you are going to process entities in chunks - why not read in the entire chunk in one query instead of N+1 queries? (with each N objects being read spinning of M queries to load their artifacts individually). Look at EclipseLink docs on batch reading for information on how to improve this

Hi @Chris, thanks for the reply. You are right, reading the entire chunk in a query would be better. I would do this, but I think the main problem is that my entity is very complex for loading maybe it is better to delete it directly in the database instead of programmatically. But thanks again

Direct in the DB is a bulk delete. If you want to avoid that - maybe so caches can be cleaned up or other lifecycle events on the objects can be triggered- you should optimize the loading of what you need to load for the delete process as that is, if I were to guess, where a lot of your time will be going. If you have memory constraints,  GC overhead might be slowing things down too, and you might want to look into batch writing optimizations - ie not flushing so often allows statements on the same table to be written out as one.
